# how do i fix this kind of AttributeError? (get_rect) in pygame

Tags: pygame, attributeerror

> im just coding along the "python crash course 2nd edition" book and
> its exatly the same code as in the book.

> here is the main.py file thats running.

```
import pygame
import sys
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship 

class AlienInvasion:
    """overall class to manage game assets and behavios"""

    def __init__(self):
        """initialize the game, and create game resources"""
        pygame.init()


        self.settings = Settings()
        

        # Window
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Kelvis Invasion")    
        

        self.ship = Ship(self)


    def run_game(self):
        """main loop for the game"""
        while True:
            # watch for ketboard and mouse events    
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
            

            # redraw the screen
            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)# set background color
            self.ship.blitme()
            

            # draw the most recent screen
            pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

> this is the second file where the Ship class is in.

```
  import pygame

class Ship:
    """a class to  manage the ship"""
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """initialize the ship and set its starting position"""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()


        # load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Alieninvasion\\images\\ship.png")
        self.rect = pygame.image.get_rect()


        # start euch ship at the midbottom of the screen
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
        

    def blitme(self):
        """draws the ship"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

> and whis is the error code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\Python 3.10\Scripts\projects\Alieninvasion\main.py", line 44, in <module>
    ai = AlienInvasion()
  File "c:\Python\Python 3.10\Scripts\projects\Alieninvasion\main.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.ship = Ship(self)
  File "c:\Python\Python 3.10\Scripts\projects\Alieninvasion\ship.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.rect = pygame.image.get_rect()
AttributeError: module 'pygame.image' has no attribute 'get_rect'
```

> maybe this is an easy fix for my problem but I dont get how this cant
> function

Comment: It  is a typo. `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` instead of `self.rect = pygame.image.get_rect()`

Comment: that was it. thank u i really was frustrated with that... <333

Answer (score 0):

It is a typo. It must be `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` instead of `self.rect = pygame.image.get_rect()`.